# managing accessibility of interface implementation memebers

Tags: c#, .net

I have an interesting scenario I've been mulling about with, wanted to know what solutions SO might have for a more elegant solution than I have come up with.

Consider the following type

```
public class Session : ISessionGraphTransitionHandler
{
   public void Handler1()
   {
      // do stuff that leverages this object instance
   }

   public void Handler2()
   {
      // do stuff that leverages this object instance
   }
   // ...

   public void HandlerN()
   {
      // do stuff that leverages this object instance
   }

   private Graph sessionGraph;

   public Session()
   {
      sessionGraph = new Graph(this); // where ISessionGraphTransitionHandler is expected
   }
}
```

Currently the interface looks something like this:

```
public interface ISessionGraphTransitionHandler
{
   public void Handler1();
   public void Handler2();
   ...
   public void HandlerN();
}
```

The problem with all this is that external actors can call `sessionInstance.Handler1()`  internal seems like it could solve this to some degree, but I'm looking for other solutions.  The idea here is that the graph should call to the parent class.  Is this a design smell? are there better ways to be solving this?

The ACTUAL types are uncleaned up and posted [here](http://pastebin.com/FNspmNwY).  I may clean them up a bit later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I get your question right, so I'm guessing a little.

```
public interface IHandler
{
    void Handle();
}

public class HandlerDirector
{
    IList<IHandler> Handlers = new List<IHandler>();

    public void AddHandler(IHandler handler)
    {
        Handlers.Add(handler);
    }

    public void RunAllHandlers()
    {
        foreach (IHandler handler in Handlers)
            handler.Handle();
    }
}
```

Now external code adds handlers using AddHandler(IHandler handler) and runs all handlers using RunAllHandlers().

Comment: Sure, not a terrible idea, however those handler classes need access to elements defined on the session.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer without knowing more about the problem you're trying to solve, and the constraints on possible solutions.   However, it does sound like you might need to use subclassing and protected members.  So for example you could leave `Handler1()...HandlerN()` out of the interface and instead declare it in a parent class as protected, possibly also as abstract if you want to force an implementation in the subclass.

```
public class ParentClass
{
    protected abstract void Handler1();
    ...
    protected abstract void HandlerN();
}

public class Session : ParentClass, ISessionGraphTransitionHandler
{
    private void Handler1();
    ...
    private void HandlerN();

}
```

Anything that should be inaccessible to external actors can be abstract members of `ParentClass`.  Anything public can be members of `ISessionGraphTransitionHandler`.

Which begs the question of why you are using an interface at all if you want to restrict 
external actors from accessing *all* of the methods in the interface.

Comment: This is a fair question, but the issue here is that the graph needs to perform actions upon some type that implements handlers that respond to the graph.  If this were as simple as just events I would do that, but this includes logic predicates.  So the graph needs a handler to provide external logic for how to respond to graph transitions (the graph is a state machine.)  An interface made more sense than injecting a crapload of anonymous delegates.

Comment: you may be looking for the C# equivalent of `friend` which unfortunately doesn't exist.

Comment: I believe that would be exactly what I want, but friend doesn't exist for a reason, how do I work around this limitation in order to make a more robust design

Comment: I haven't found a satisfying workaround.  You can do some somewhat hackish things using type extensions and refusing the wrong `this` types at runtime, but as far as I know there is no known reasonable C# workaround to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

One reasonable solution here is to leverage the Explicit Interface Implementation mechanic in C# to only allow the interface elements to be accessed via the IEncounterTransitionHandler interface, marking the interface as internal and assuming that developers will not abuse this type internally.